# Deploying .NET 8 aot lambda function to aws from mac

Tags: .net, amazon-web-services, lambda

I am unable to deploy a .NET 8 lambda function using aot from my m series mac. I have been following the directions in the documentation here https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/dotnet-native-aot.html but I cannot get it to deploy. The steps work perfectly fine on windows but I get an error when running it on mac.

I run the command `dotnet lambda deploy-function` and I get the error

> Host machine architecture (Arm64) differs from Lambda architecture (X64). Building Native AOT Lambda functions require the host and lambda architectures to match.

The documentation says that the deploy lambda cli command should handle the docker setup but it seems like it's not building it properly. I created my own dockerfiles and specified to use linux-x64 as the target but I still get the same error. What am I missing? Is it really saying that I cannot deploy from my arm  computer to aws even when I use docker images?

I have tried creating dockerfiles to make my host environment the same as the target environment but it still throws the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to specify the architecture that you will use. Could you try to add `-farch arm64` option? you can find the options with `dotnet lambda deploy-function --help` command.

Comment: Yep that worked! Really feel like a fool now. Thank you